# WebStorm shows reserved word at import

Tags: node.js, meteor, coffeescript, webstorm, rocket.chat

I'm using WebStorm to edit rocket.chat project which based on Meteor,
but the WebStorm always shows 'reserved word' warning at `import` on Coffee files. The project runs well -- it seems only the WebStorm config problem.

Here are my WebStorm settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm probably has outdated definitions for CoffeeScript code inspections.

From [CoffeeScript Official Website](http://coffeescript.org):

> 1.11.0 — SEPTEMBER 24, 2016
>
> CoffeeScript now supports ES2015 import and export syntax.

Before CoffeeScript 1.11 import and export were reserved words.